# Need guidance with addressing possible duplicate account issue

Tags: discussion, duplicate-accounts

Within the last hour I was reading questions on SO, and came across a question posted by a user. While reading *that* question I attempted to post a comment and found that the question was deleted.  Then a little later, the *same* question was posted by a new user, which lead me to believe that the original poster created a new account to circumvent the possibility of receiving any negative reputation on their original account.

My understanding is that duplicate accounts on SO are frowned upon when used in a way that aim to circumvent the reputation system. If my understanding of this is invalid, please let me know.

So how should situations like this be handled?  Should I simply flag the question for a moderator to assess? Or if this practice is ok, please let me know and I'll ignore it.

There is a remote chance that I may be incorrect as I have no way of viewing the original question that was posted since it was deleted by the original poster; however, when I read the 2nd posted question, and saw the account name of the person that posted an edit to the 2nd question, my radar went off and I knew something was fishy because I recalled that name as the account holder for the original question that was posted moments prior.

Comment: Duplicate accounts are generally not an issue as long as they stay separated. Once they start interacting with each other you get into "puppet accounts". As for your case, it could be the original author deleted the first question, and reposted (which in most cases is ok).

Comment: So my advice: if you can't prove it, don't flag it. If it's only happened once: don't flag it. If you can clearly see that it's happen multiple times, then you can flag it.

Comment: Well, I may not be able to prove it, but a mod could. ;) In any case, I'm going to let it go, but the guidance is helpful.

Comment: Maybe the user was on the edge of a question ban and deleting his question triggered it. He then created a new account to post that question... but if the question is of decent quality then leave it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The mere existence of a duplicate account is not at all a problem. There are just a couple times when it can be:

1. They are being used to 'cheat' for reputation, e.g. by voting for each other.
2. They are being used to circumvent restrictions, such as question/answer bans, suspensions, and the like.
3. They are being used to 'gang up' on someone, via voting, harassing, etc.

If there doesn't appear to be anything clearly egregious going on, you can generally leave it; things tend to come out 'naturally'. You should give the benefit of the doubt, and if the account seems to be 'behaving', you might want to err on the side of letting it go.

But if the person seems to be abusing the extra account(s) in some way, you can consider an "Other" flag on one of their posts (or even yours), and explain as best you can. Moderators will look into it and "Do the Needful".

---

<sup>And here's a bonus secret: If someone finds some small way around some block/ban, but they end up being a good contributor after; [well, we win!](http://xkcd.com/810/) :)</sup>

Comment: You forgot [the obligatory link](http://xkcd.com/810/) for your bonus secret.

Comment: Some people have two accounts, one for work and one for home. That way they can use their account help them remember the context of the reason for their question. I worked with someone that had 3 accounts: Work, Home, Non-profit charity work.

Comment: @CodyGray I have *no idea* what you are talking about... ;)

Comment: @Brian Yup; and I've heard anecdotes that some might create separate accounts for asking and answering.

Comment: I am one of those single account guys. I hate remembering multiple log-ins. :) However, yes @AndrewBarber there are cheaters, and there always will be.

Comment: @Brian I came across one today: [1st account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7933597/user71311), [2nd account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8267705/gerald) Check out his posts if your curious. He used them to avoid a question ban, so I felt it was fitting to flag for moderator attention(which I did).