# User admitting to multiple accounts

Tags: discussion

There is a particularly ungrateful member [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654836/c-sharp-mimic-click-or-corresponding-click) and then being more than a little rude to those he has asked for help.

What got my attention was this assertion he made in a comment on the linked question:

> Sadly, i have been preforming a Survey & Ratings on "Developer Support" Communities, Forums & Blogs. The Lines of coding i have seen here are horrible sadly improper my friends i've done 3 months of lurking and reviewed tons of questions never have a correct line of coding been given to one. i've asked 20 question under 14 different users and Neither one of them were answered correctly or i have to code swap just to make something as simple as Recieving cords work properly when it doesnt take all of that. For the record

Stack Overflow has a policy of no multiple user accounts as far as I'm aware.  Does this require further attention?  Given the poor attitude if nothing else, I would suggest that the earlier accounts were all banned or locked out.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having multiple accounts as long as they aren't doing anything wrong (like voting fraud). That being said, I would really like to see this user have a change of attitude as well.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You are being more patient than me, I decided it wasn't worth my time debating with him.  "Never argue with an idiot, they drag you down to their level and beat you with experience." :)

Comment: I'm done with him as well at this point. I'll keep closing his questions as self-duplicates if he continues the behavior though.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Creating another account to bypass an account restriction is a pretty serious problem, though. ;) From my experience, though, a lot of users that claim "I've used a gagillion different accounts" are just making crap up because they're frustrated at how horribly their question was received and want to make it sound like a bigger problem than it is.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I also flagged as duplicate.  I wish I could flag him for "being a drain on my limited time I choose to give to Stack Overflow" :/

Comment: We could definitely use a "This user just doesn't care about our standards" or "is being a jerk" flag. I like "being a drain on my time on SO" flag as well. :)

Comment: He seems to be doing C# questions? I want a showdown between him and Jon Skeet :D

Comment: @Julldar I was tempted to challenge him to that, then decided it was time to stop feeding the troll. Go right ahead though :D

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Feature request? ;)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I have a tendency to not feed trolls honestly, even if you're right it's a waste of time.  This user is simply not the kind we want on this website, and I won't entertain him :P  + I think we ALL know how that showdown would end....  I mean the guy is an OBVIOUS troll... "I've made over 4K projects!".... that is what?  100 projects a YEAR in a 40 years career?  so.... he finishes a PROJECT in 3 days?

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and say that people aren't going to go for a user-targeted flag like that (since we are supposed to judge posts, not users) but I would sure like one... A "challenge Jon Skeet" button would be an **AWESOME** feature though.

Comment: Who could win a Jon Skeet challenge?..... besides, obviously... Jon Skeet

Comment: @Julldar Thats the point, we could just make all the trolls do it :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Don't worry, I was actually joking about that particular flag :)  But a John Skeet challenge flag?  I so vote for that! :)

Comment: @JaneS I'd agree _@animuson's comment says it all: [We take care about sock puppets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268267/suspicious-users-found-active-only-one-day-many-upvotes-cast/268279#268279) and their behavior.

Comment: Quote: "i've done 3 months of lurking and reviewed tons of questions never have a correct line of coding been given to one. i've asked 20 question under 14 different users and Neither one of them were answered correctly".  Somebody step up that plate please.  Anybody?  Bueller?

Comment: @HansPassant +1 for the Ferris Bueller reference! :)

Comment: I don't think this guy actually has multiple accounts.  There's nothing in the moderator tools that suggests anything but he, himself and him, using a single account.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would have thought that there would be some tools available to mods for flagging multiple accounts by MAC address or something similar.  But since he volunteered it (with such an arrogant attitude), I thought I would ask :)  With his clear lack of knowledge of project schedules, I suspect he is just a kid.

Comment: Is his avatar a pic of Eric Bana?

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes it is.

Comment: He has also worked on 4 thousand projects. That's mighty impressive.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I know! Why he ever had to come here and ask a question is beyond me! :) /vapid expression

Comment: You can help us to handle users like this. Always make sure to *downvote* their low-quality questions, thereby pushing them closer to an automatic question ban. If appropriate, you should also flag/vote to close the question. This saves other users from wasting their time trying to post an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do when I see a user with multiple accounts, and what action will be taken?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260430/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-a-user-with-multiple-accounts-and-what-action-will) and/or [On the use of multiple accounts to pre-emptively get around a question ban](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262060/on-the-use-of-multiple-accounts-to-pre-emptively-get-around-a-question-ban)

Comment: I recently had an experience with a user having multiple accounts where he used his two accounts to vote down and try to close my question costing me rep, along with voting up his own accounts. I did report, little was done to my knowledge. My big concern now is with the new careers page, given rep and tags are used by an automated system to target you for job consideration, reputation and abuse by multi account holders now has an actual impact on ones career. I feel this should be looked at properly in light of the new careers system and its impact with regard to such people.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The simple act of having multiple accounts is no problem, according to @AndrewBarbers answer to [Need guidance with addressing possible duplicate account issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270474/need-guidance-with-addressing-possible-duplicate-account-issue?cb=1)

> The mere existence of a duplicate account is not at all a problem. There are just a couple times when it can be:
>
> 1. They are being used to 'cheat' for reputation, e.g. by voting for each other.
> 2. They are being used to circumvent restrictions, such as question/answer bans, suspensions, and the like.
> 3. They are being used to 'gang up' on someone, via voting, harassing, etc.

That being said, the user is trolling so it would seem to possibly merit a custom flag (though with the existing moderator attention, I'm not sure anything needs to be done *right now* for this user).